# How to set a personalized port as default in Apache?

Tags: server, apache2

My website work only if I run:

> domain.com:44400

How to set port 44400 as the default in Apache?

I need have access by domain.com not domain.com:44400

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make the server accept connections on both port 44400, on all interfaces, use:

```
Listen 44400
```

To make the server accept connections on port 44400 for one interface,  use

```
Listen domain.com:44400
```

Open your apache2.conf file.  To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Setup Listen as follows:

```
Listen 44400
```

Save and close the file. Restart the apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Verify that Apache listing:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :44400
```

Comment: Is port 44400 blocked by the default firewall rules?

Comment: I can't personally verify it.  Port 44400 is TCP CSTM Port for DFM, HUM Applications, and its Direction (of Establishment) of Connection is Server Internal. It can be used to run to Warsow servers on port 44400 on the same server, if the server have two IP addresses. So I don't thinks it blocked.

Comment: This can also be added to and changed in the conf file for the site itself in /etc/apache2/sites-available

I added the Listen 44400 line to the top of the file, and changed the port at

 <VirtualHost _default_:44400>

This leaves the rest of the server alone, allowing you to use it as normal, but changes the port for a specific site. (useful if you're doing virtual hosting)

Answer (score 14):

In /etc/apache2/ports.conf, change the port as

```
Listen 44400
```

Then go to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

And change the first line as

```
<VirtualHost *:44000>
```

Now restart

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Apache will now listen on port 44000 and redirect to /var/www/html

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04**. In order to change apache2 default port, change it in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file as;

```
Listen 44400
```

**Note:**

Adding Listem 44400 in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file,then apache will listen on 80 and 44400 both ports.

Comment: It's also working with Ubuntu 17.04. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open httpd.conf in /etc/apache2 and write:

```
Listen 44400
```

Comment: Depending on your setup, you also have to change your virtual host configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-available to include the port to listen on.

Answer (score 0):

To have access by domain.com

write

> listen 80